# Using websockets with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I send a request to the server, which launches creating files there, then client gets a response and creating files proceeds. Then websocket is used to message client about progress. I try to send a message after every file created. Client gets first message but then doesn't while other files are being creating. Is this because of quantity of messages?

I suppose to send message not for each file, but, for example, for each 10th or 20th, or make a delay there. So I'd like to ask skilled colleagues how to do it properly?

server code:

```
    //send value of ZipFinished until client gets true value 
    const sentData = { progressCreatePDFs: true, 
                         PDFNumber: PDFNumber, 
                         totalPDFs: totalPDFs }; 
    
    webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(sentData)); console.log('server webSocket sent number of created PDF ' + PDFNumber + ' of ' + totalPDFs);
```

client code:

```
    webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
       //get message object
       const messageObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
    
       if (isAboutProgressCreatePDFs(messageObject)) {
          //handle getting progress of creation PDFs
          console.log('ws client got progress of creatiuon PDFs');
    
          infoPara.style.display = 'block';
          infoPara.innerHTML = '' + messageObject.PDFNumber + ' of ' + messageObject.totalPDFs +  ' PDFs created';
            infoPara.style.color = colorProgressCreatePDFs;
          }
    
        };
```

Comment: Can you please provide code snippet or code block for sending sockets?? both client and server?

Comment: In theory what you describe works just fine, so something is wrong with how you wrote it.

Comment: @VladimirShestakov use the `edit` button and use syntax highlighting. This is quite painful to read.

Comment: sorry, I dont' know how to format it here

Comment: Don't be sorry, use a quick moment to learn and edit your question, not the comment. The question itself should have all the information for someone to help you solve the issue.

Comment: agree, edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that sending too many websocket messages in quick succession can sometimes overwhelm the client. There are a couple ways to handle this:

1. Batch messages into fewer updates: Instead of sending a message per file, collect them and send batches of updates (e.g. every 10 files or every 2 seconds).

```js
let batch = [];

files.forEach(file => {
  // add file to batch 
  batch.push(file);  

  // check if ready to send
  if(batch.length >= 10 || Date.now() - lastUpdate > 2000) {
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify(batch)); 
    batch = [];
    lastUpdate = Date.now(); 
  }
})
```

2. Use socket acknowledgements - wait for the client to acknowledge before sending the next update. This prevents overwhelming the socket while ensuring messages are received properly.
3. Use a queue (like Redis Pub/Sub) instead of direct websocket messages. This helps smooth spikes in updates.

Overall, throttling frequency and size of messages based on the client capability helps prevent message loss. Start with simpler batching, then use queues or acks if needed.

Let me know if any part needs more clarification!

Comment: That's what I need, going to dig it deeper on my own, thank you!